# SwiftでUserDefaultsに構造体のArrayを保存したい。

Tags: swift

SwiftでUserDefaultに構造体のArrayを保存したく、
以下のコードを書いたのですが、

```
// コンテンツを保持する構造体
struct ROContents : Codable {
    var idString_: String       // コンテンツを一意に識別するID文字列
    var titleString_: String    // タイトル文字列
    var readOutString_: String  // 読み上げる文字列

    // 規定イニシャライザ
    init() {
        idString_      = ""
        titleString_   = ""
        readOutString_ = ""
    }
}
```

・・・

```
func save() -> Bool {

    let userDefaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    let data = contentsArray_.map { try? JSONEncoder.encode($0) }
　　　　　・・・

    return true
}
```

以下のエラーが出てしまいます。
'ROContents' is not convertible to 'JSONEncoder'
ROContentsで何らかのプロトコルを実装しないといけないのでしょうか。

=== 追記 ===

ご指摘頂いた通りに以下のようにメソッドを修正しました。

```
func save() -> Bool {

    let userDefaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    do {
        let data = try encoder.encode(contentsArray_)
        userDefaults.set(data, forKey: "contentsArray")
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return false
    }

    userDefaults.set(contentsCounter_, forKey: "contentsCounter")

    return true
}

func load() -> Bool {

    let userDefaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let data = userDefaults.data(forKey: "contentsArray")
        contentsArray_ = try [decoder.decode(ROContents.self, from:　data!)]
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return false
    }

    contentsCounter_ = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "contentsCounter")

    return true
}
```

実行してみた所
save()の方は問題なかったのですが、
load()の方は、以下のエラーが発生してしまいます。

typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

戻り値がDictionaryなのに、配列（Array）に入れようとしている。
ということだと思うのですが、decodeのやり方が間違っているのでしょうか。

Comment: ご質問への情報の追記ありがとうございました。回答に追記部分への返信を追加しましたので、お確かめの上、何かあればコメント等でお知らせください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentsArray_`は`[ROContents]`型として宣言されているものとします。このように重要な情報は必ずご質問中に記載するようにしてください。

(識別子の末尾に`_`をつけているのはどう言う理由でしょう? Swiftのコードとしては滅多に見られないものなので、できればやめた方が良いでしょう。)

`JSONEncoder`クラスの使い方が誤っています。`encode(_:)`はクラスメソッドではなく、インスタンスメソッドなので、まずは`JSONEncoder`クラスのインスタンスを作成しなければいけません。

```
        let encoder = JSONEncoder() //<-`JSONEncoder`のインスタンスを作成する
        do {
            let data = try encoder.encode(contentsArray_)
            //...
            return true
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return false
        }
```

(`JSONEncoder`の使い方が100%理解できていない状態で`try?`を使うことはお勧めできません。実行時エラーが発生した場合にエラー情報が捨てられてしまうので、原因究明が困難になります。)

出来上がった`data`をどう使うつもりなのかによっては、後続のコードも修正の必要があるかもしれません。ご質問中では省略されてしまっているので、具体的には書けませんが、`UserDefaults`に保存するのが目的ならば、大きな変更にはならないはずです。

***=== 追記 ===*** 部分への回答

保存と読み込みは当然ながら対になっていないといけません。

私の回答に基づいて更新された`save()`のやっているのは、概ねこんな感じです。

```
構造体のArray ([ROContents]型)
　　↓JSONEncoder.encode(_:)で変換
Data型
　　↓UserDefaults.set(_:forKey:)で保存
UserDefaults内のDataオブジェクト
```

これの逆をやるのですから、こう言う風にしないといけません。

```
UserDefaults内のDataオブジェクト
　　↓①
Data型
　　↓②
構造体のArray ([ROContents]型)
```

このうち①の部分、「UserDefaults内のDataオブジェクト」から`Data`型として値を取り出す部分は、あなたのコード(`data(forKey:)`で取り出し)で間違いありません。

②の部分で何が間違っているかは、お分かりでしょうか。「`JSONEncoder.encode(_:)`で変換」の対になるメソッドとして`JSONDecoder.decode(_:from:)`を使っているのは良いのですが、変換対象の型の指定が間違っています。UserDefaultsに保存された`Data`の元は`Array<ROContents>`(=`[ROContents]`)型だったのですから、`[ROContents]`型を指定してやらないといけません。

この行

```
        contentsArray_ = try [decoder.decode(ROContents.self, from:　data!)]
```

を

```
        contentsArray_ = try decoder.decode([ROContents].self, from:　data!)
```

と書き換えてください。

`decode(_:from:)`メソッドの第一引数は「〜型に」を表しているのですから、その部分に「構造体のArray」を表す型を記述します。

そのままだと`data`がnilの時にクラッシュしてしまうので、私ならこんな感じに書くでしょうか。

```
    func load() -> Bool {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            guard let data = userDefaults.data(forKey: "contentsArray") else {
                print("contentsArray cannot be found in UserDefaults")
                return false
            }
            contentsArray_ = try decoder.decode([ROContents].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return false
        }

        contentsCounter_ = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "contentsCounter")

        return true
    }
```

(ちょっとした不注意でアプリがクラッシュしてしまう`!`が出てこないことに注意してください。)

---

既にご存知かもしれませんが、`UserDefaults`と言うのは「設定」アプリにある各アプリの設定画面程度の量の設定データを保存することを意図したクラスです。ユーザがアプリを使い続けると`[ROContents]`に何百何千ものデータが溜まっていく、と言った場合には、データの保存先としては適切ではないので、念のため。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
ご教授頂いたコードで、正常に動作するようになりました。

Answer (score 0):

> contentsArray_は[ROContents]型として宣言されているものとします。  
>   このように重要な情報は必ずご質問中に記載するようにしてください。

申し訳ありません。省略してしまいました。  
以後、気をつけます。

> (識別子の末尾に_をつけているのはどう言う理由でしょう?   
>   Swiftのコードとしては滅多に見られないものなので、  
>   できればやめた方が良いでしょう。)

Objective-C時代からの名残で、メンバ変数には、  
末尾に”＿”を付けております。

ご指摘の通りに書き換えて試したところ、  
UserDefault に保存出来ました！  
ありがとうございます！

ただ、今度は、読み込みの方でエラーが出てしまいます。

```
func load() -> Bool {  
    let userDefaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard          
    contentsArray_ = userDefaults.array(forKey: "contentsArray") as! [ROContents]  

    return true  
}
```

こちらも変更する必要がありますでしょうか。  
宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: 別な質問として質問を立てた方が良いと思いますが、`JSONEndocer().encode()` で`encode`した`Data`型のインスタンスを`UseerDefaults`から取り出すのですから、`JSONDecoder().decode(ROContents.self, from: data)`で元に戻さないと配列に戻ってくれないと思いませんか？

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。しかし、「回答」はそのような報告や追加の質問を書く場所ではありません。簡単な内容ならコメントで、ちょっと複雑になるなら内容に応じて、質問への追記か、別質問としていただくべきところです。今回の場合、**元質問に`load()`の定義が含まれていれば** 当然回答にも含めたであろう内容なんで、質問への追記の形でも構わないだろうと思います。「編集」から元質問を編集して、新たな情報を追加するようにしてください。現在の`save()`がどうなっているのかを省略なしに含めていただいた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: 質問に追記させて頂きました。
saveメソッドの方は問題なかったのですが、  
loadメソッドの方でエラーが発生してしまいます。  
ご教授お願い出来ますでしょうか。  
宜しくお願いいたします。